# How do a I setup mongodb messagestore in aggregator using annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to add an aggregator to my code. 
Couple of problems I am facing. 
1. How do I setup a messagestore using annotations only. 
2. Is there any design of aggregator works ? basically some picture explaining the same.

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class Aggregator {


    @Aggregator(inputChannel = "abcCH",outputChannel = "reply",sendPartialResultsOnExpiry = "true")
    public APayload aggregatingMethod(List<APayload> items) {
        return items.get(0);
    }

    @ReleaseStrategy
    public boolean canRelease(List<Message<?>> messages){

        return messages.size()>2;
    }

    @CorrelationStrategy
    public String correlateBy(Message<AbcPayload> message) {
        return (String) message.getHeaders().get(RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-annotations) we have a note:

> Annotation configuration (`@Aggregator` and others) for the Aggregator component covers only simple use cases, where most default options are sufficient. If you need more control over those options using Annotation configuration, consider using a `@Bean` definition for the `AggregatingMessageHandler` and mark its `@Bean` method with `@ServiceActivator`:

And a bit below:

> Starting with the version 4.2 the `AggregatorFactoryBean` is available, to simplify Java configuration for the `AggregatingMessageHandler`.

So, actually you should configure `AggregatorFactoryBean` as a `@Bean` and with the `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "abcCH",outputChannel = "reply")`.

Also consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) to simplify your life with the Java Configuration.

Comment: I have added aggregator... now the issue is generic message does not have no arguments constructor...so saving  message to mongodb store is failing

Comment: Do we have any mapping converter mongodb for generic message

Comment: Which available out of box

Comment: Yes we do. Show, please, your store config and stacktrace on the matter